# Convert Object Type in dataframe to Int / float / String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object, type-conversion

My dataframe has the following column types, and below 3 records from the dataframe are shown. I am trying to convert the columns with type 'object' to 'int' or 'string' or 'datetime' or 'float'.

For some reason the data is in square brackets and I want to eliminate those two while performing the conversion. Because of the square brackets I think commands like `df = df.astype(int)` are not working. I also tried `df['age_mod'] = df['age'].astype(str)` but the type still remains as 'object'.

How do I convert from 'object' type while ignoring the square brackets?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `df["age"][0]` to eliminate brackets.

Comment: Is the output of `type(df['age_mod'][0])` `list` ?

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict()` as [edit] to your question

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine that doesn't "eliminate brackets".

Comment: Clarification: `df["age"][0]` get the first (and apparently only) item in the list, indicated by the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do something like this

```
df['age'] = (list(df['age']))[0][1:-1]
df['gender'] = (list(df['gender']))[0][2:-2]
df['joined_co'] = (list(df['joined_co']))[0][2:-2]
df['became_exec'] = (list(df['became_exec']))[0][1:-1]
df['age_mod'] = (list(df['age_mod']))[0][1:-1]

df['age'] = df['age'].astype(float).astype(int)
df['age_mod'] = df['age_mod'].astype(float).astype(int)
df['joined_co'] = pd.to_datetime(df['joined_co'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```